# Capturing Lync video stream

Tags: rtp, lync, lync-2010, ucma, lync-server-2010

Is it possible to somehow capture a video stream of a lync conference in lync 2010 or 2013? I've got the beta running in our labs. UCMA provides hooks for AudioVideoFlow but only seems to operate on the audio side.. Is it possible to get a direct pointer to the RTP stream somehow? I assume there's some provision, I see other products that claim to do it, but I can't find any documentation on an approach.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do it in UCMA - AudioVideoFlow is currently the only flow available.

You'd have to look at the SIP traffic to determine the traffic and then packet capture I imagine. I believe this is how third party vendors do it.